# How can I use a mouse with another USB receiver dongle of the same model?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, mouse, dongle

I have:

- A: a working Microsoft Wireless Mouse 3500  + a totally broken USB receiver dongle (in fact I already threw the broken dongle away)
- B: a not-working-great Microsoft Wireless Mouse 3500  + a healty USB receiver dongle

**How can I use mouse A with USB dongle B?**

Should it be done:

- via simple software action? by setting the ID of the mouse on the USB receiver?
- firmware reflashing?
- swap some electronic parts from the one to the other? (I already opened the mouse with Torx screwdriver, and I have access to the PCB)? I guess it would be a chip connected to the wireless emitter, containing the ID of the mouse?

Comment: Logitech has "unified receiver" that can be paired with several wireless Logitech-made devices (keyboard and mice) using a software applet. But I haven't heard about such feature on Microsoft RF products.